# Change IP Address in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, ip, wmi, ip-address

I am writing a Windows Forms App in VB.Net that will (among other things) change the IP Address, Default Gateway, Subnet Mask, and set the IP Address to Static on an image of Winfows 7 only. Sysprep is not being used. I have searched Google and only come up with 2 options. I don't believe the first solution will work for me because I do not necessarily know the name of the connection. It uses netsh to change IP settings. I was going to give a link to this example but I can't post more than 2 links...

The second solution is shown at [this link (the VB.Net version)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/3ca76e36-a737-4486-835d-874f71b22dc5) and the original code is [here (the C# version)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5697/Configuring-TCP-IP-Settings-using-WMI-and-C). This solution uses WMI which I really don't know that much about.

When I debug the code and look at everything the code seems to be executing properly but the IP Address is still set to DHCP and all of the other setting are still the same. So, basically, what gives? Why does this code seem to not work?

Here is my code. I only made a few changes:

```
    'Changed the 3 IPs below
    Dim IPAddress As String = "192.168.1.105"
    Dim SubnetMask As String = "255.255.252.0"
    Dim Gateway As String = "192.168.1.100"

    Dim objMC As ManagementClass = New ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration")
    Dim objMOC As ManagementObjectCollection = objMC.GetInstances()

    For Each objMO As ManagementObject In objMOC
        If (Not CBool(objMO("IPEnabled"))) Then
            Continue For
        End If

        Try
            Dim objNewIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
            Dim objSetIP As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing
            Dim objNewGate As ManagementBaseObject = Nothing

            objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic")
            objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways")

            'Set DefaultGateway
            objNewGate("DefaultIPGateway") = New String() {Gateway}
            objNewGate("GatewayCostMetric") = New Integer() {1}

            'Set IPAddress and Subnet Mask
            objNewIP("IPAddress") = New String() {IPAddress}
            objNewIP("SubnetMask") = New String() {SubnetMask}

            objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, Nothing)
            objSetIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, Nothing)

            'Changed this line so I could see if it was executing all of the way
            MessageBox.Show("Updated IPAddress, SubnetMask and Default Gateway!")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to Set IP : " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next objMO
```

Comment: [This is the link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/443895/ip-address-changer-using-vb-net) that I could not provide in the above post.

Comment: I can answer my own question...in 7 hours.

Comment: Do *not* ignore the return value of InvokeMethod(), it will provide an error code if the method failed.

Comment: Doesn't the Try...Catch...End Try catch the error code from InvokeMethod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer my own question. I thought of it in the shower (how cliche right?). Because this is Windows 7, all I needed to was right-click and run the program as an administrator.